# Eslint configuration is showing a `definition for rule 'filenames/match-regex' was not found` error

Tags: eslint

I'm getting started with Walmart's new React framework called [Electrode](https://github.com/electrode-io/electrode-boilerplate-universal-react-node).

I'm trying to configure eslint and have tried extending the walmart lint configuration like so:

https://github.com/walmartlabs/eslint-config-walmart

Here's the .eslintrc

```
{
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "env": {
        "es6": true
    },
    "extends": "walmart/configurations/es6-react-test",
    "rules": {
        "indent": ["error", 2]
    }
}
```

and package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
    "electrode-archetype-react-app-dev": "^1.0.0",
    "eslint": "^2.10.2",
    "eslint-plugin-filenames": "^1.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^5.1.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1"
  },
```

but I get a `definition for rule 'filenames/match-regex' was not found` error.  I installed eslint-plugin-filenames, was there something else I need to confgure as well?

```
file: 'file:///foo/client/components/home.jsx'
severity: 'Error'
message: 'Definition for rule 'filenames/match-regex' was not found (filenames/match-regex)'
at: '1,1'
source: 'eslint'
```

Comment: Try adding this to your `.eslintrc`: `"plugins": [
    "filenames"
  ],`

Answer (score 2):

Try running ESLint from your `node_modules` instead of the one you have installed globally. Something like this:

`node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js --fix .`

Otherwise your ESLint plugins might not get picked up.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading the packages, I don't see any such issues now with the new versions.

For configuring/overriding default `eslint` config refer the [Electrode docs](https://docs.electrode.io/chapter1/intermediate/app-archetype/eslint.html)

For example to override default `eslint` config for `client`(react), I created a `.eslintec` file in `client` folder, with below snippet:

```
---
extends:
  - "../../node_modules/electrode-archetype-react-app-dev/config/eslint/.eslintrc-react"
  - "eslint:recommended"

parser: 
  "babel-eslint"

rules:
  quotes:
    - 2
    - "single"
```